# Faces messages not displaying in p:messages

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I am new to PrimeFaces and I am having trouble getting simple validation messages to display. Below is my simple JSF page. Can someone point me in the right direction as what I am doing wrong?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>Add Tournament</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>       
            <h:form>
                <p:layout fullPage="true" >
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <f:view>
                        <div align="center">
                            <h1><h:outputText value="Create/Edit Tournament"/></h1>
                            <p:panel>
                                <p:messages globalOnly="false" id="msgs" autoUpdate="true"/>
                                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="TournamentName:" for="tournamentName"  />
                                    <p:inputText required="true" id="tournamentName" value="#{tournamentProfile.tournament.tournamentName}" title="TournamentName" requiredMessage="Tournament name is required." />
                                    <p:outputLabel value="" for="addTournament" />
                                    <p:commandButton validateClient="true" update="msgs"  id="addTournament"  value="Add Tournament" />
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </div>
                    </f:view>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tiny default value for `globalOnly` is `false` .

Comment: BTW i tested this code and it is working perfect for me !

Comment: Maybe in this (unspecified) PF version there is a conflict between the explicit `update="msg"` in the commandButton and the `autoUpdate="true"`.  @Scorpion: maybe your (unspecified) PF version does not support the autoUpdate or it is newer and the conflict is not there. So **please, please, please** always specify version info when posting or replying

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry for this oversight, I am using PF 5.1, JSF 2.1

Comment: I am using PF 5.0 and JSF 2.2. I also have multiple theme jars. Is there anything wrong with having multiple theme jars? Could there be a potential class with the various jars?

Comment: I have been able to get the messages to fire. However they are showing as a bullet point list and not the same style as the primeface showcase example.

Comment: My issue is resolved and the messages are displaying. Sad to say I am not sure exactly what the problem was. I just re-created the page from scratch. My guess is that some version of the file was cached which was causing the problem. Thanks everyone for taking the time to provide suggestions.